# What is the benefit of tableless design if you need clearing blocks everywhere?

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

I understand that the goal of moving towards `<div>` tags from `<table>` makes sense since it is more semantic. However, I don't understand the benefit gained if you still need a clearing block to make column-based layouts work. For example:

```
<!-- Note: location-info & personal-info both float left. -->
<div class="contact"> 
    <div class="personal-info">
        <p>
           Shawn, etc, etc
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="location-info">
        <p><address>etc</address></p>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both" /> <!-- clearing block -->
 </div>
```

The extraneous `<br>` tag is used strictly to describe style, and is required to make the layout work. Doesn't this ruin all benefits gained from removing tables?

Comment: For what it's worth, if you're displaying tabular data (and it looks like you are) you should still use a table.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What if I told you [you](http://www.sitepoint.com/simple-clearing-of-floats/) [didn't](http://www.innovatingtomorrow.net/2008/03/24/how-clear-floats-css) [need](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html) a clearing block?

```css
.clear-block:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.clear-block {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="clear-block">
    <div style="float:right">
        Your content here
    </div>
    <div style="float:left">
        More content here
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3vnbz4p/)

Comment: I think you'll find it is, the magic word being "hasLayout" - try ctrl+f for IE6 on any of those three links

Comment: IE8 finally gets rid of the hasLayout nonsense. About 10 years overdue, but we have to take what we can get... :)

Answer (score 11):

If you are displaying tabular data, it still makes more sense to use tables then many floated divs. Use the tools you have wisely - don't blindly use CSS where tables are the best option.

Comment: Heh, this is true as well, it's good to see this advice, means that people is doing the right thing, mostly :)

Comment: True, although I wouldn't say tables are the best choice here. This isn't what I'd call tabular data.

Comment: only the OP would know exactly. To me it sounds as if he's trying to display tabular data without tables.

Answer (score 8):

> I understand that the goal of moving towards `<div>` tags from `<table>` makes sense since it is more semantic.

Actually, it's exactly the opposite: moving from `<table>` to `<div>` makes your HTML *less* semantic. In fact, the *whole point* of the [`<div>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) (and [`<span>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element)) elements is to have *no* semantics!

It always ticks me off, when I see a forest of `<div>`s described as "semantic HTML". No, it's not! That's *un-*semantic HTML! Especially if it contains a lot of `<div class='float-left'>`, `<div id='bottom'>` and my personal favorites `<div class='paragraph'>` and `<span class='emphasis'>`.

Don't get me wrong, using un-semantic `<div>`s is certainly better than using *wrong*-semantic `<table>`s, but even better would be to use the semantically *correct* elements – although in many cases the problem is that HTML doesn't offer any. In your snippet for example, you use the `<address>` element, but according to [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-address-element), this element is *not* meant for marking up addresses! It is *only* for marking up the address *of the author of the page* – IOW it's utterly useless.

The example that you posted is missing a lot of context, so it is hard to say, but it actually looks like you might want to display either tabular or hierarchical data, in which case `<table>`s or `<ul>`s might be a better choice.

---

Totally unrelated to your question: you might want to take a look at the [hCard](http://Microformats.Org/wiki/hCard) and [XOXO](http://Microformats.Org/wiki/XOXO) microformats.

Comment: There is some meaning to a div - division.

Comment: Look at his example, it has far better semantics than a table-based equivalent. The divs indicate that the contained information is semantically related. The classes such as "personal-information" semantically identify the information. All you've said here is "if you assign classes really badly and use the wrong tags, it's not more semantic. Well duh!

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. There are LOTS of other benefits to avoid using tables.

- [Tables instead of DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251/tables-instead-of-divs)
- [DIVs vs. TABLEs a rebuttal please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96137/divs-vs-tables-a-rebuttal-please)
- [DIV's vs. Tables or CSS vs. Being Stupid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61250/divs-vs-tables-or-css-vs-being-stupid)

Comment: im talking about in this specific situation, a 2 column layout

Comment: The answer is valid to that specific situation as well. It's a lot better to use what you have than use tables. This way you have 1 extraneous tag (which can be mostly ignored), the other way you'd have at least 10 which cannot be ignored.

Comment: Additionally, it seems to be superfluous, as annakata's link shows.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the clearfix hack for my clearing needs.

```css
/* Clearfix */
#content:after,
.box:after {
  content:'.';
  display: block;
  clear: both; 
  visibility: hidden; 
  height: 0;
}
#content,
.box {
  zoom: 1; /* IE */
}
```

Notice I just comma separate the selectors rather than adding the `clearfix` class to everything. It works really well. The only problem is that the `zoom` property is IE specific and doesn't validate, but there are no side effects like there can sometimes be with other properties, like `overflow: auto`.

I've been using this in professional websites for 5 years with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

As annakata's answer shows, you don't need  those clearing blocks. But apart from this, one advantage to avoiding tables is that the page can be rendered progressively. A table can only be rendered when the *entire* table, including all its contents, has been parsed, which may take a while if you have a big page and a slow connection. divs can be rendered immediately, which means you might be able to present something usable to the user much sooner than with tables.

Of course, this is just a nice little bonus advantage, it isn't, and shouldn't be *the* reason to avoid tables (for non-tabular data)