# CSS: Why don't these two div (or span) elements float next to each other

Tags: html, css, css-float, block

In the following code, I need the div elements `#ldiv` and `#rdiv` to be placed next to each other.

So I am using the CSS `float` property. I [looked up this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446060/css-two-divs-next-to-each-other), and I think I am following it, but still the div's won't position next to each other. The second `div` displays in the next line.

Then I thought that `div` is a block level element, so I replaced the `div` by `span` elements. But that did not help either.

[**JSFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/41209azo/)

```
<div style="padding:25px; width:400px;">

    <div style="background-color:#bf5b5b;">
    <span>Yes</span>
    <span>No</span></div>

        <div id="option_one_div">
            <div id="ldiv" style="float:left; background-color:#74d4dd; width:150px;">
            <label for="rbutton_radio_1_0" style="margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px;">
                <input for="rbutton_radio_1_0" type="radio" name="radio" value="0"/></label>
            <label for="rbutton_radio_1_1" style="margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px;">
                <input for="rbutton_radio_1_1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1"/></label>
            </div>
            <div id="rdiv" style="float:right; background-color:#74d4dd; margin-left:151px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px">
            <span>Label of first group of Radio Buttons radio buttons.</span>
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your situation you can use `display:table` in container(`#option_one_div`) in your example and  `display:table-cell` in children elements(`#ldiv`, `#rdiv`) like this:

```
<div style="padding:25px; width:400px;">

    <div style="background-color:#bf5b5b;">
    <span>Yes</span>
    <span>No</span></div>

        <div id="option_one_div" style="display: table;">
            <div id="ldiv" style="background-color:#74d4dd; width:150px;display:table-cell;">
            <label for="rbutton_radio_1_0" style="margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px;">
                <input for="rbutton_radio_1_0" type="radio" name="radio" value="0"/></label>
            <label for="rbutton_radio_1_1" style="margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px;">
                <input for="rbutton_radio_1_1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1"/></label>
            </div>
            <div id="rdiv" style="display:table-cell; background-color:#74d4dd; margin-left:151px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px">
            <span>Label of first group of Radio Buttons radio buttons.</span>                
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/41209azo/6/)

As you can see you don't need `floats`.

Answer (score 2):

use width with float in div

```
<div id="rdiv" style="float:right; background-color: #74d4dd; /* margin-left: 151px; */ padding-left: 20px; width: 210px;padding-right: 20px">
            <span>Label of first group of Radio Buttons radio buttons.</span>
            </div>
```

[plz check](http://jsfiddle.net/akash4pj/41209azo/1/)

Answer (score 2):

the total width of the elements (incl. margin/border) can not be greater than the surrounding divs width of 400px else the floating elements will be put into the next line ... see akz's answer for a quick fix

Comment: I tested this by increasing the width to 500px, no gain! So I think this is not due to width problems

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `float:right`. It will work.

```
  <div id="rdiv" style="background-color:#74d4dd; margin-left:151px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px">
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/41209azo/2/)

Comment: you also might want to remove the `margin-left:151px;` that would look a tad nicer

Answer (score 0):

the main problem is you didn't add width to the `id="rdiv"` and used `margin-left:151px`
when you use some element with float, you have to add its width

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left;width: 110px;height: 90px;margin: 5px;">a</div>
    <div style="float: left;width: 110px;height: 90px;margin: 5px;">b</div>
    <div style="float: left;width: 110px;height: 90px;margin: 5px;">c</div>
</div>
```

to solve the problem, you can do one of the following things:

1: change your code to:(notice you set margin-left:151px; in th `id="rdiv"` and I changed it to lower value)

```
<div id="rdiv" style="float:right; background-color:#74d4dd; margin-left:15px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; width:50px;">
```

2: remove your `float=right` in the `id="rdiv"` so the id="ldiv" could be in the float version of this element