# Why the does the ul in this nav not come after the previous div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The `ul` tag does not come after the previous `div` in the same line, (the one with the class `Logo`).

I want to show the `ul` tag after the `logo` tag, in the same line. However, the `ul` goes  under the line that I want to show it in.

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    direction: rtl;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 700px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #007bff;
}

nav {
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
}

nav ul {
    width: 60%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.Logo {
    width: 160px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.Logo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="Logo"><img src="Content/img/logo.png" alt="جاب بورد"></div>
            <ul></ul>
                <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </nav>

    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Positioning Elements Next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705804/css-positioning-elements-next-to-each-other) Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504670/css-why-dont-these-two-div-or-span-elements-float-next-to-each-other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add display:inline-block to both the logo and the ul

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
   /* direction: rtl; */
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 700px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #007bff;
}

nav {
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
}

nav ul {
    width: 60%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
}

.Logo {
    width: 160px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.Logo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="Logo"><img src="Content/img/logo.png" alt="جاب بورد"></div>
            <ul></ul>
                <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </nav>

    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ul` and `div` elements are block-level, meaning they take 100% width and will stack on top.

In order to have them beside each other you will need to use `floats`, `inline-block`, `flexbox`, or `grid`.

I would suggest flexbox for this case.
Add `display: flex` to the direct parent element

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    direction: rtl;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 700px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #007bff;
}

nav {
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
}

nav ul {
    width: 60%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.Logo {
    width: 160px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.Logo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="Logo"><img src="Content/img/logo.png" alt="جاب بورد"></div>
            <ul><li>List Here</li></ul>
        </nav>

    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

flexbox is really the way to go.  You need to add margin-top:100px to the ul

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    direction: rtl;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 700px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #007bff;
}

nav {
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
}

nav ul {
    width: 60%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-top:100px;
}

.Logo {
    width: 160px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.Logo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="Logo"><img src="Content/img/logo.png" alt="جاب بورد"></div>
            <ul><li>List Here</li></ul>
        </nav>

    </header>
</body>
```