# How to keep the two div tag in one line vertically?

Tags: html, css

I have tried every option but i am unable to keep the div in one line.Please help me out.
I have attached the code

```css
.showdetailsleft {
  margin: 1%;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 1%;
  float: left;
}

.showdetailsright {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="showdetailsleft">
  <label>Course Information</label>
  <hr class="divider">
  <p>Course Summary</p>
  <p>je fiu ewfi u ew iub fiu ewb iu bfi weu bf iub qiu eiu biwe eu ib fiu we ube wiu fbew iuw ebfi uwe fi u e biuw weubf iwe ub fiw iwebf iuw ebiw ebfi weu b uwef biuw ebfiw weiu fei wub iu biweh git ro inna db wo nwq ivb foiqw noqj giw ejj bb</p>
  <div class="showdetailsright">
    <label>How to Enroll</label>
    <hr class="divider">
    <p>je fiu ewfi u ew iub fiu ewb iu bfi weu bf iub qiu eiu biwe eu ib fiu we ube wiu fbew iuw ebfi uwe fi u e biuw weubf iwe ub fiw iwebf iuw ebiw ebfi weu b uwef biuw ebfiw weiu fei wub iu biweh git ro inna db wo nwq ivb foiqw noqj giw ejj bb</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vertically or  Horizontally ..?  coz you are saying about the Div's in line so i  am asking

Comment: Horizontal next to each other

Comment: can you change the html structure.?

Comment: Can u please give me the solution??

Comment: i have given the answer please check it out

Comment: yes but you don't have margin on that div, just padding

Comment: only margin on the top, not a general margin

Comment: no problem :) anytime

Comment: Can u share  your mail id so i can take the help from u??Delete it after sometime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had one div contained within the other div which is why it could neever vertically align to the top (the right div) . I adjusted the widths to account for padding and margins.

```css
body {
  margin: 0!important;
  padding: 0!important;
}
.showdetailsleft {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 56%;
  padding: 1%;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}
.showdetailsright {
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 38%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 1%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="showdetailsleft">
  <label>Course Information</label>
  <hr class="divider">
  <p>Course Summary</p>
  <p>je fiu ewfi u ew iub fiu ewb iu bfi weu bf iub qiu eiu biwe eu ib fiu we ube wiu fbew iuw ebfi uwe fi u e biuw weubf iwe ub fiw iwebf iuw ebiw ebfi weu b uwef biuw ebfiw weiu fei wub iu biweh git ro inna db wo nwq ivb foiqw noqj giw ejj bb</p>
</div>
<div class="showdetailsright">
  <label>How to Enroll</label>
  <hr class="divider">
  <p>je fiu ewfi u ew iub fiu ewb iu bfi weu bf iub qiu eiu biwe eu ib fiu we ube wiu fbew iuw ebfi uwe fi u e biuw weubf iwe ub fiw iwebf iuw ebiw ebfi weu b uwef biuw ebfiw weiu fei wub iu biweh git ro inna db wo nwq ivb foiqw noqj giw ejj bb</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked but when increase my width the second div is getting below the first..Why is so?

Comment: because you have margins and padding on your divs, you must take that into consideration

Comment: a margin of 1% adds a margin of 1 on all sides, the same for padding, and body has natural padding id you don't remove it

Comment: 56+2% margin+2% padding is 60, and 38 +2% padding is 40

Comment: ok i want width of 70 and 30 so i also have to change the margin and padding?

Comment: you just have to change the main widths up one by 10 and minus the other by 10, you can leave the padding and margins the same

Comment: yes ofcourse u vil get an upvote:) But one thing i am not getting is that in .showdetailsrights class  the width should be 26% because you said margin 1% padding1% will be padding 30??

Answer (score 2):

Hi Shakira here it's your desired solution

please check it out

```css
.wrapper{
    display:block;   
}
.showdetailsleft{   
 margin:1%;
 width:55%;
 padding:1%;
    float:left;
}
.showdetailsright{
 width:39%; 
 padding:1%;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="showdetailsleft">
    <label>Course Information</label>
    <hr class="divider">
        <p>Course Summary</p>
        <p>je fiu ewfi u ew iub fiu ewb iu bfi weu bf iub qiu eiu biwe eu ib fiu we ube wiu fbew iuw ebfi uwe fi u e biuw weubf iwe ub fiw iwebf iuw ebiw ebfi weu b uwef biuw ebfiw weiu fei wub iu biweh git ro inna db wo nwq ivb foiqw noqj giw ejj bb</p>
</div>
<div class="showdetailsright">
    <label>How to Enroll</label>
    <hr class="divider">
        <p>je fiu ewfi u ew iub fiu ewb iu bfi weu bf iub qiu eiu biwe eu ib fiu we ube wiu fbew iuw ebfi uwe fi u e biuw weubf iwe ub fiw iwebf iuw ebiw ebfi weu b uwef biuw ebfiw weiu fei wub iu biweh git ro inna db wo nwq ivb foiqw noqj giw ejj bb</p>
</div>
</div>
```

here is the demo for this code
[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/a2cyjxrv/)

**Here why it will not work with 60%-40% ratio to both div**

@shakira it's because browser's size is 100%.
now if you see that **(1st div's width(60%) + 1st div's padding(1%) +1st div's margin + 2st div's width(40%) + 2st div's padding(1%) +2st div's margin  ) always more than 100%.** 
so next div will come in down that's why it will not work and you need to adjust those width.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked but when i increase my width to 60 to 40 then the second div comes below the first.. why is it so?

Comment: @shakira it's because browser's size is 100% now if you see that **(1st div's width(60%) + 1st div's padding(1%) +1st div's margin + 2st div's width(40%) + 2st div's padding(1%) +2st div's margin  ) always more than 100%** so next div will come in down that's why it will not work and you need to adjust those width.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below solution and modify it for your needs.
Same question have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446060/css-two-divs-next-to-each-other) if you want more insight.

This should help you out:

**Div 1 -- on the right side**

```
.showdetailsleft 
{
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
}
```

**Div 2 -- on the left of Div 1, covering the entire available area**

```
.showdetailsright
{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 200px;
}
```

Hope this helps you out.