# Place to divs side by side fails

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to put two divs next to each other but what I get is shown in the picture.

This is my code:

```
             <div id="leftColumnSvg ">
                <p> sdsadasd</p>
                <p> sdsadasd</p>
                <p> sdsadasd</p>
                <p> sdsadasd</p>
             </div> 

             <div id="rightColumnSvg">
                <svg width="160" height="160">
                  <circle cx="80" cy= "80" r="60" style="fill:#00cc00"/> 
                  ................

                </svg>
             </div>
```

And my CSS is:

```
#leftColumnSvg 
{
 background-color:red;
 width:200px;
 float:left;
}



#rightColumnSvg{   
 width:300px;
 float:right;
}
```

I thought it should work like this as also shown [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446060/css-two-divs-next-to-each-other)

[image]

Comment: It's seems that the popup's width is less than 500px. If so, you need to enlarge the popup (if you can) or reduce the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note how the background colour to the text is not red either.

You have a trailing space in your ID attribute value, so the selector doesn't match at all.

```css
#leftColumnSvg {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
#rightColumnSvg {
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftColumnSvg ">
  <p>sdsadasd</p>
  <p>sdsadasd</p>
  <p>sdsadasd</p>
  <p>sdsadasd</p>
</div>

<div id="rightColumnSvg">
  <svg width="160" height="160">
    <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="60" style="fill:#00cc00" />................

  </svg>
</div>
```

When I remove it, it works.

```css
#leftColumnSvg {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
#rightColumnSvg {
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftColumnSvg">
  <p>sdsadasd</p>
  <p>sdsadasd</p>
  <p>sdsadasd</p>
  <p>sdsadasd</p>
</div>

<div id="rightColumnSvg">
  <svg width="160" height="160">
    <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="60" style="fill:#00cc00" />................

  </svg>
</div>
```