# How to display two divs together in html?

Tags: html

I want to show two divisions side by side. I have tried a few possible solutions, but they still overlap. Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .sidebar
    {
        width:200px;
        background:yellow;
        color:orange;
        padding:50px;
    }
    .content
    {
        width:600px;
        background:silver;
        color:red;
        padding:50px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
       <div class="sidebar">
        This is sidebar div
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        This is Content div
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS two divs next to each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446060/css-two-divs-next-to-each-other)

Comment: use bootstrap,it make it simple

Answer (score 2):

Use `float:left;` **[Learn about CSS float Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)**

```css
.sidebar
    {
        width:150px;
        background:yellow;
        color:orange;
        padding:50px;
  float:left;
    }
    .content
    {
        width:200px;
        background:silver;
        color:red;
        padding:50px;
  float:left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
 This is sidebar div
</div>
<div class="content">
 This is Content div
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .sidebar
    {
        width:200px;
        background:yellow;
        color:orange;
        float:left;
        padding:50px;
    }
    .content
    {
        width:200px;
        background:silver;
        color:red;
        float:left;
        padding:50px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
       <div class="sidebar">
        This is sidebar div
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        This is Content div
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think do you mean just display two div in one row is it right so it is just simple add float:left in first div it will solve your issue.

Like :

```
    .sidebar {
        width: 200px;
        background: yellow;
        color: orange;
        padding: 50px;
        float:left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .sidebar
    {
        width:200px;
        background:yellow;
        color:orange;
        padding:50px;
        float:left;
    }
    .content
    {
        width:600px;
        background:silver;
        color:red;
        padding:50px;
        float:left;
        margin-left:10px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sidebar">
        This is sidebar div
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        This is Content div
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added main parent to both div and used display:inline-flex to it.

```css
.main{
  display:inline-flex;
}   
.sidebar
    {
        width:200px;
        background:yellow;
        color:orange;
        padding:50px;
    }
    .content
    {
        width:600px;
        background:silver;
        color:red;
        padding:50px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="sidebar">
        This is sidebar div
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        This is Content div
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding float:left to both div will fix the issue.

> css code:

```
 .sidebar
    {
        width:200px;
        background:yellow;
        color:orange;
        padding:50px;
        float:left;
    }
    .content
    {
        width:600px;
        background:silver;
        color:red;
        padding:50px;
        float:left;
    }
```

> html code:

```
 <div>
         <div class="sidebar">
           This is sidebar div
         </div>
         <div class="content">
           This is Content div
         </div>
    </div>
```

and if one of your div is going down then you must adjust your div's width.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a float:left to the widgets

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem :

You should add this code to `.content` and to `.sidebar`

Add `float:left`...

This should help

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp..

glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Since `div` is a `block` level *element*, so it will occupy 100% width of its *immediate parent*. Because of it, one cannot place them in a horizontal manner without making use of `float` - a very useful **CSS** property.

So in your CSS you should add the property as below, to get the desired result:

```
.sidebar {
     float: left;
}
```

Watch the demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/3mjo64h0/).

To get more information about *float*, one can always Google, as it is an ocean of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

use `CSS float Property`

```
float: none|left|right|initial|inherit;
```

```css
 .sidebar {
   width: 200px;
   background: yellow;
   color: orange;
   padding: 50px;
   float: left;
 }
 .content {
   width: 200px;
   background: silver;
   color: red;
   padding: 50px;
   float: left;
 }
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  This is sidebar div
</div>
<div class="content">
  This is Content div
</div>
```