# Wordpress two column layout help. Side bar and the body will not be same heights!

Tags: css, wordpress

First of all here the work in progress website link http://jacobnlsn.com/wordpress/. I want the bars to be the same height.  Here is what i have in CSS for both:

```
#bodybinblog {
width:546px;
float:left;
background:#400000;
border-left:solid 9px #cdba70;
border-right:solid 9px #cdba70;
margin:0 15px 0 30px;
padding:0;
}

#sidebarbinblog {
width:229px;
height:inherit;
float:left;
background:#400000;
border-left:solid 10px #cdba70;
border-right:solid 10px #cdba70;
margin:0 0 0 11px;
padding:0;
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Ironic that you're using "Programmer, Designer, Coder" in your site while asking this question.

Comment: check out  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699/on-a-two-column-page-how-can-i-grow-the-left-div-to-the-same-height-of-the-right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the tricks designers use in webdesigns is the laying of background images. In this case, you want the sidebarbinblog to assume the same height as the bodybinblog because you want the background to fit nicely. If the sidebar's height is higher than the body, same problem will occur but this time on the body side.

The solution is to create a background image of maybe 1px horizontally capturing both for the body and the sidebar. Apply that background on the container div of both the body and the sidebar Repeat-y it so it spans the full height.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use "faux columns". Here is a useful link - http://dustinbrewer.com/tutorials/fauxcolumns/

It should work like magic.